# Randomly select from multiple columns per group

Tags: r

My data are as follows:

```
data <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), value = c("1", "4", "5", "3", "3", "5", "3", "5", "1", "4", "2"), treatment = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "A","NA"), retain = c("88", "664", "797", "131", "88", "997", "645", "88", "13", "79", "5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

For each group, I would like to randomly select a value and a treatment, and have them be from the same row. I would like to apply this selection to every row within the respective group, and retain the observations as they are under the column 'retain'.

My desired output could be something as follows:

```
data <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), value = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "2", "2", "2"), treatment = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "NA", "NA","NA"), retain = c("88", "664", "797", "131", "88", "997", "645", "88", "13", "79", "5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a sample of sequence (`row_number`) `by` 'group' and use that index to subset the values in columns 'value', 'treatment'

```
library(dplyr)#version>= 1.1.0
data %>%
   mutate(rn = sample(row_number(), 1), across(c(value, treatment), ~ .x[rn]),
     .by = group) %>% 
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
   group value treatment retain
1      1     1         A     88
2      1     1         A    664
3      1     1         A    797
4      1     1         A    131
5      2     5         C     88
6      2     5         C    997
7      2     5         C    645
8      2     5         C     88
9      3     4         A     13
10     3     4         A     79
11     3     4         A      5
```

---

Or another option is to `slice_sample` without the 'retain' column by group and use `rows_upsert`

```
data %>%
  select(-retain) %>% 
  slice_sample(n =1, by = group) %>%
  rows_upsert(data, .)
```

-output

```
  group value treatment retain
1      1     5         B     88
2      1     5         B    664
3      1     5         B    797
4      1     5         B    131
5      2     5         C     88
6      2     5         C    997
7      2     5         C    645
8      2     5         C     88
9      3     1         A     13
10     3     1         A     79
11     3     1         A      5
```